# Android studio (0.9.1) beta - Ctrl+F1 hotkey

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm just a beginner so apologize for silly question.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> hotkey was always for displaying error. But now when i press this combination there is some painting tool appearing. I've tried to change it back but couldn't find this combination (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) in Settings -> Keymap, as well as couldn't find the name of the functionality that describes error (what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> did before).
Is it a bug? How can I revert <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to do what it always did?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what that is, I've never seen it in AS. Are you sure it's not some external color application that is capturing your input. Otherwise, select a different preset for the Keymaps, apply it and then change back to the on you are currently using.

Comment: Thanks @free3dom.
You were right - it was external program (Maxton browser). As soon as i disabled it - everything started to work fine. (Well - almost everything, ctrl+R doesn't work though, but it's ok).

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted out.